# How can you add custom supply symbols in Eagle?

Tags: power-supply, eaglecad

I have multiple 3.3V 5V, 5.2V, 4.8V, and 13V supplies. I tried copying a device from the supply library to mine and renaming the symbol and device, but when connecting it still refers to it as the original voltage supply device net.

Whats the proper/easy way to create a new, custom, and perhaps duplicate voltage supply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the pin name of the symbol to the desired net name. Symbol, device names are less important here. Here's more info (pasted directly from Eagle 7.2 manual, sect.8.5):

> 8.5 Supply Symbols
>
> Supply symbols, such as might be used in the schematic for ground or VCC,
>   are defined as Devices without a Package. They are needed for the automatic
>   wiring of supply nets (see page 127).
>   The following diagram shows a  GND symbol  as it is defined in one of the
>   supplied EAGLE libraries.
>   Note that when defining your own supply symbols, the pin and the Device
>   name need to agree.
>   The pin is defined with direction  sup and has the name GND. This specifies
>   that   the   Device   containing   this   Symbol   is   responsible   for   the   automatic
>   wiring of the GND signal. The text variable for the value (>VALUE) is chosen
>   for the labeling. The Device also receives the name GND. Thus the label GND
>   appears in the schematic, since by default EAGLE uses the Device name for
>   the value.
>   It   is   very   important   that   the   labeling   reproduces   the   pin   names,   since
>   otherwise the user will not know which signal is automatically connected.
>   The pin parameter Visible is therefore set to off, since otherwise the placing,
>   orientation and size of the pin name would no longer be freely selectable.
>   Directly labeling with the text GND would also have been possible here. With
>   the   chosen   solution   however,  the   Symbol   can   be   used   in   various   Devices
>   (such as for DGND etc.).

I suggest reading the whole section, it's less than 2 pages long.